# How can I use for date range queries for Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, couchdb

I have some documents have field of lastUpdateDateTime like: 
"2016-11-02 17:36:55","2016-07-02 17:36:55","2016-01-02 17:36:55",

I defined index like following

```
   r.add(doc.lastUpdateDateTime, {
       field: 'lastUpdateDateTime',
        store: 'yes'
    });
}
```

I used Lucene date range query like...q:lastUpdateDateTime:[20160101 TO 20170101], but I did not get expected results, please advice thanks

Comment: i think this field will be a plain string, which will not help you to do range queries

Comment: @ Mysterion, thanks,    is there any way I can change the field type in the index so that I can make this do this range query?

Comment: this all code you have?

Comment: @ Mysterion, yes, I wonder if I can do this via index defined in lucene above and then do range queries like q= lastUpdateDateTime:["2016-07-01"+TO+"2017-07-31"]? thanks

Comment: You will need to store the date in a appropriate form, e.g. as a `longPoint`; then you can use a `RangeQuery`, for example `LongPoint.newRangeQuery`. But it depends on which version of lucene you are using.